# Подключить оплату на сайт с помошью карт VISA

Tags: карты

Подскажите пожалуйста, сервисы которые предоставляют API для оплаты картой VISA услуг или считав на сайте.

Разные робокасы и остальные посредники не нужны, нужно именно подключение без посредников.

Например захожу на яндекс диск, кликаю оплатить карой, и попадаю на их же страницу с их дизайном, или сайт линголео, жму оплата картой и тоже полностью их дизайн, даже не понятно через кого настроена оплата.

Я же пытался через ликпэй подключить, но у них там бардак, документация не сходится с тем что от их сервера приходит, поддержка тупит и стрелки перекидывает, уже около недели мурыжу, оплата то проходит, но сохранять статистику и вести журнал оплат чертовски сложно, можно попасть в просак когда будет не понятно кто оплатил. Ну и чтобы оплатить нужно 3 или 4 раза нажать подтверждаю, а каждый клик это вероятность что пользователь передумает делать покупку.

Comment: Можно с банками пообщаться просто, выяснить у кого наиболее удобные условия.

Answer (score 1):

Вполне возможно, что вам подойдет сервис:http://ufcenter.com.ua/ и сертификаты у них все в открытом доступе, то есть прозрачный бизнес и нужно по минимуму документов для регистрации.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите в сторону http://ishopnew.qiwi.ru/

Comment: Не то. Не уточнил что нужно для Украины. Ну и формат киви платежей не подходит, вижу это не эффективным способом оплаты для своего сайта.